# HTTP Request with content-length > 0 but body is empty in docker container

Tags: docker, http, groovy, envoyproxy

I am trying to run curl commands in a groovy script and containerize it using docker. The script runs a bunch of curl commands. Using the following code to execute the commands.

```
    def process = commandArray.execute()
    def out = new StringBuffer()
    process.consumeProcessOutputStream(out)
    if (process.isAlive()) process.waitForOrKill(240000)
```

Things work fine when I run locally. But When I execute the groovy script in container the response body comes as empty but the Content-Length will be more than 0.

My headers are as below(Have Replaced few content with dummy data, ex: xyz.com)

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xyz.com (10.20.30.400) port 80 (#0)
> GET /abc/xyz/type HTTP/1.1
> Host: xyz.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< cache-control: no-cache, private
< etag: "000000000000000000000000000000"
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< x-frame-options: DENY
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 72950
< date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 06:17:09 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 57
< server: envoy
<
{ [15940 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host xyz.com left intact
```

Although the content-length: 72950 when I print the **out** object, it is empty []
What might be going on here? This issue is specific to running in container

The curl command looks as below

```
curl -s -v -L -k -X 'GET' --cert '/tmp/groovy-generated-10305010891926264191-tmpdir/client-cert.pem' --proxy 'https://proxy.com:30000' --noproxy 'localhost,127.0.0.1' 'https://example.com/abc/xyz/type'
```

Comment: Curl in container is not printing the data to output. Show your curl command, and the OS in container.

Comment: @daggett Added the curl in the question above. Not sure about the OS but I am using base image **groovy:3.0.8-jre11** which internally uses **adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot**

Comment: What can be the reasons for Curl not printing the data to output?

Comment: There could be unprintable chars. And different curl implementations on different OS.

Comment: Try to run your curl command from container and redirect out to file to check what curl gives in stdout.

Comment: @daggett  I was able to run successfully by adding a `sleep(50)`  between lines `def out = new StringBuffer()` and  `process.consumeProcessOutputStream(out)`

Comment: I was able to make this work after adding a 50 ms delay before `process.consumeProcessOutputStream(out)`. The response was being returned properly but there was some delay needed to write the long responses.